# MS PowerApps, If after Switch in powerapps, so it's executed independently (after switch, not inside)

Tags: function, powerapps, multiple-conditions

I have problem with PowerApps function, that I cannot resolve myself.
Below you can find a code, that work (allthough I assume it isn't well optimized). As in topic, the if condition is executed inside switch, as one of it's arguments, instead of being executed AFTER switch. The end result should be: user presses the button, that applies filter on table, and after that if condition comes in to play, and does it's job.

The main part is if condition, when user selects criteria in dropdown menu, the condition sorts table with name or rating. Inside that condition, there are functions to support search engine and sort ascending/descending button.
After that I wanted to add support for filter buttons, and the buttons itself work fine, but the if condition is executed only when the last button is pressed (so when e. g. I press It-related button, it sets category to "1" and navigates to next screen, but searching/sorting doesn't work).
I tried to separate conditions with more parenthesises, adding ";;"at the end of switch, but it didn't resolve problem (additionaly broke app).

```
Switch(
    category;
    1;
    Filter(
        Table1_2;
        '4. Area of training' = "IT-related"
    );
    //here is a bunch of filters for categories from 2 to 4
    5; //no filter as it should display table without any filter
If( //the problematic if, that is executed only when category is "5"
        dropdown_sort.Selected.Value = "Name of the training"; //check what the value of dropdown is, and the execute positive or negative case
        SortByColumns(
            Search(
                Table1_2;
                search_engine.Text; //takes text input and searches inside column below
                "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"
            );
            "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"; //sorting on this column
            If( //to change ascendin/descending on button press
                sort;
                Ascending;
                Descending
            )
        );
        //here is second part of if, that is basically identical to above (it sorts different column), and executes case when selected value of dropdown is different that "Name..."
    )
)
```

I would like if to execute regardless of the switch. Additionally, if there is a way to do it better, please write your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Most of my observations are already known to you but still let me try to put it out.
In your current code for switch case, If statement is clearly inside your switch and that too for category =5 and hence it fires only for category for 5.
What you are trying to achieve here is called "chaining operation". As you already tried ;;and this did not helped how about simply try ;
Also have a look at this link it will give you more idea, let me know if this helps.


https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Chaining-operation-doesn-t-work-Expected-an-operator/m-p/237819#M69804

Comment: I rearranged a code a bit to meet my requirements and managed to get it work (unfortunately in the stupid way). I will try your suggestion in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the final answer but based on what I read I will try something like below.

```
if( category=1;
    Filter(
        Table1_2;
        '4. Area of training' = "IT-related"
    );;If( //the problematic if, that is executed only when category is "5"
        dropdown_sort.Selected.Value = "Name of the training"; //check what the value of dropdown is, and the execute positive or negative case
        SortByColumns(
            Search(
                Table1_2;
                search_engine.Text; //takes text input and searches inside column below
                "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"
            );
            "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"; //sorting on this column
            If( //to change ascendin/descending on button press
                sort;
                Ascending;
                Descending
            )
        );
        //here is second part of if, that is basically identical to above (it sorts different column), and executes case when selected value of dropdown is different that "Name..."
    )
    category=2;
    Filter(
        Table1_2;
        '4. Area of training' = "IT-related"
    );;If( //the problematic if, that is executed only when category is "5"
        dropdown_sort.Selected.Value = "Name of the training"; //check what the value of dropdown is, and the execute positive or negative case
        SortByColumns(
            Search(
                Table1_2;
                search_engine.Text; //takes text input and searches inside column below
                "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"
            );
            "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"; //sorting on this column
            If( //to change ascendin/descending on button press
                sort;
                Ascending;
                Descending
            )
        );
        //here is second part of if, that is basically identical to above (it sorts different column), and executes case when selected value of dropdown is different that "Name..."
    )
    //here is a bunch of filters for categories from 2 to 4
    category=5;  

)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a meantime I managed to solve it myself, similarly to what you suggested. The code is identical for false value and another categories. Anyway, thanks for your help.

```
Switch(
    category;
    1;
    If(
        dropdown_sort.Selected.Value = "Name of the training";
        SortByColumns(
            Search(
                Filter(
                    Table1_2;
                    '4. Area of training' = "IT-related"
                );
                search_engine.Text;
                "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training"
            );
            "3_x002e__x0020_Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_training";
            If(
                sort;
                Ascending;
                Descending
            )
        );
```